# GitLab runner configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, runner

I am using standard GitLab runner.

I need to determinate updates of master branch and updates of development branch. Beacause I want to copy master branch to production server and dev branch to test-server.

But I have only one .gitlab-ci.yml file which starting after 'git push'.

If I am register second runner. it is also controller by .gitlab-ci.yml

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

In gitlab ci config file, we have the only option allowing to trigger a job only from a specified branch.

Doc at docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except